# Register existing domain name to dedicated server

Tags: dns, domain-name

I have a dedicated server which has Ubuntu installed and also I have a domain name. I want to register this domain name for my dedicated server host but I couldn't do that. What is the steps for this?

I have webmin on it and I also have binddns on server

When I enter my domain name in the browser I want it to forward to my dedicated server host root web directory

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to do three things:

1)Have you domain registrar (e.g. GoDaddy) assign the correct IP address to your DNS server. If you're running a DNS task on your own server, it would be the IP address of that server. Most registrars want two DNS servers, so you might want to find a friend with a server who can act as your backup.

2)Configure your DNS server with an "A" record saying that yourdomain.ext is 111.111.111.11, or whatever your IP address really is.

3)Configure Apache (or whatever web server you're using) to respond to requests sent to yourdomain.ext by sending the index file in the "root web directory".

Comment: Hi Carlf,I have a domain name registered in godaddy.I have got the 3 dns services of the company that i bought dedicated server from.After that,i changed my dns services accourding to that in go daddy domain manager.Am i in correct way?

Comment: I'm not certain I'm understanding you. If I do understand correctly, the missing step is to have your provider configure their 3 DNS servers to point your domain to your dedicated server.